# UITableViewCell constraints error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a view different UITableViewCells, depending on the content one of those cells will be loaded, however 1 cell is messing with me.

I'm trying to add it to the Table View, but my constraints are messing with me. With the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints on true it displays fine, however I get the well known error message regarding constraints. Setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false, seems to completely mess up the layout, especially height wise.

```
  class videoCell: UITableViewCell {


       override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
           super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
           playerView()
       }

       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
       }

       func playerView() {

            let height = self.frame.width * 9 / 16
            let vpFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: height)
            let vpView = vpView(frame: vpFrame)

            //vpView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            vpView.sizeToFit()

            addSubview(vpView)

            vpView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            vpView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
            vpView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
            vpView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true   

       }

   }
```

The error with translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints on false:

> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>   Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want.

I also have this one set:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: You are mixing `.frame` settings with auto-layout constraints. In general, you should use one or the other, and *definitely* not both on the same object. Is `vpView` a fixed-size view? Or does it have variable, dynamic content and you want it to auto-size its height?

Comment: just as @DonMag said. Try removing frame/height/width lines and only use constraints. Then *if* needed, try adjusting your constraints. Also don't forget to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`

Comment: It has dynamic width, height, in which the controls are placed inside the player. I’ll try removing the frame settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you mixing Frame-based layout rules and Autolayout rules.
A frame based layout is what you did in your code by calculating the size and the width of your vpview. 
The Autolayout constraints are what you did by activating some anchor constraints for location attributes (top,bottom,left,right).

By default when you add a view, there are some prototyping constraints settled by default. That's why by default `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is equal to true.

So if I take your code in your function `playerView` you are saying to the compiler :

- Don't worry I compute the height for this view by myself
- Then you disable your frame layout based and said to the compiler to handle this by putting anchor constraints.
- RESULT => The compiler is lost obviously because the size that you compute (height, width) and your anchor constraints have conflicts.

So you have to decide by computing yourself your sizes and locations for your views OR use autolayout. Then on your error console you can list all the conflicted constraints and try to resolve them.

P.S : One advice when you want to fix left right anchor constraints, you should prefer trailing and leading anchors. Apple recommends it. And to go any furthere is the Apple documentation to learn about layout and autolayout : [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1)